# Adding a new landcover type to existing landcover raster file

Tags: land-cover, nlcd

I have a NLCD raster file and I want to add pavement landcover type to the NLCD raster file. How can I create a new landcover raster file in ArcGIS Pro that has both NLCD and paved raster?

Comment: Maybe the `con` function will help you

Comment: Yes, It worked but combined with "IsNull" 
I used something like this. Con(IsNull(first raster), 2nd raster, 1st raster)

Comment: It would be nice if you posted a complete answer with print screens and everything with the parameters you used and the output so others can follow your solution. But I'm glad it worked